# REST API decision - create a new api or use existing

Tags: javascript, rest, api

I have a web app which has multiple pages accessed via different urls. For e.g. on page "index", i am hitting an end point (`/index`), which returns me around 20 data items in JSON.
And on page "settings", i am hitting another end point, say `/settings`. Now, i have a scenario, where in i need one data item from the end point `/index` on page "settings".

So,

1) should I be calling that end point again on page "settings" and get that data item. I just need a single field from that end point, nothing else

2) should I probably be adding that field to be returned in the endpoint `/settings`

3) or probably create a new end point which is called on "settings" page along with `/settings`

Is it generally easy to decide based on just these inputs or it also depends on how the API is further interacting with DB and how tables are structured there?

Comment: If you need that one piece of data more often than you need the whole dataset, make a new endpoint.  Otherwise, you'll be pulling down too much data, and processing the whole thing for no reason each time.

Comment: well, that item is not needed always as compared to the whole data set. Whole data set is always needed on "index" page, but on "settings" page, that one item might be needed conditionally only. Would it still make sense to create a new one

Comment: Could you add a parameter to your rest call to ask for a specific field, and return the whole set if no field is provided?  That would eliminate the need for a new endpoint, while serving both purposes.

Comment: Would that be okay from REST perspective, as in a single url returning data conditionally, like multiple data vs one

Comment: From REST perspective you typically design endpoints for what they accept/deliver, not where they get used. Adding parameters for any specific endpoint is normal

Comment: Hey @charlietfl , would it be possible for you to elaborate on this, what you said, would be real helpful. May be an example, if it okay

Comment: for example:  Your endpoint could be domain.com/api/settings  and the parameter could look like domain.com/api/settings/field    or domain.com/api/settings?field=abc

Comment: okay, good. Thanks for the help here @nixkuroi